# Connecting MS Access to Oracle SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, ms-access-2003

I want connect my MS access 2003 with Oracle SQLdeveloper so that I can do analyis in SQLDeveloper. I am trying to create ODBC driver but it is not working.I am wondering if any of you send me the links or explain how can I create a ODBC connection between Access and Oracle SqL developer

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/node/60

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short [video](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/ms-access-connection-viewlet-swf-086613.html)

and a more complete example is in [this article](http://www.packtpub.com/article/ms-access-queries-with-oracle-sql-developer-one-point-two-tool)

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do it:
**Long & foolproof method:**
1. Below link has he Oracle Tutorial document for the Migration

*https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/msaccess/migrate_microsoft_access_otn.htm*

**Short Method (may not work always):**
2. To setup a connection to MS Access in Oracle SQL Developer, from the Connections dialog, click on the green plus sign. This will open the connections dialog box.

You will see a tab that says Access right beside Oracle tab which will be selected. Click on the tab to open up the dialog to use an MS Access MDB file. Use the Browse button to locate the MDB and give it a connection name. No need to enter username.

Once connected to the MS Access database from Oracle SQL Developer, you will see the connection in the database.

You can see all the tables in the database by expanding the TABLE category of the connection.