# Connect to a MS Access database with SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, ms-access, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a Microsoft Access database (.accdb extension) that I would like to query with SQL developer version 19.4. Is this possible? and how do I achieve this?
I am not planning on migrating the database, I would just like to be able to query it with SQL (as I am not familiar with Access).

When I create a new connection I don't have the possibility to select Access in a tab with this version of SQL developer. When I use an older version it is there, but it doesn't support the extension of my Access database.

I found this as well: [Connecting MS Access to Oracle SQLDeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469025/connecting-ms-access-to-oracle-sqldeveloper)
But the suggestions done there are not suitable for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible.

We used to offer this functionality via a odbc-jdbc bridge, but that went away with Java 7 I believe.

We've not built native support for an Access JDBC driver.

If you can find a copy of SQL Developer version 3, you can do what you want, out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, sql developer 4.0.3 also has Access and can open Oracle 19c.

Answer (score 0):

You may need the driver:

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

Then you can create a *Linked Server* using your *accdb* file as source.